# Merging Same Values and Output it as One

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need some help in SQL, I have the below table, and I want to remove duplicate values from column (AMOUNT) and keep only one value as per the below table#2, so what's the best practice to cater this using SQL?

Table#1

```
| ID  | TRANS. ID | AMOUNT 
| 2   | 30001     | 15    
| 3   | 30001     | 15
| 4   | 30001     | 15
| 5   | 30002     | 88    
| 6   | 30002     | 88
| 7   | 30002     | 88
```

I want to output to be as below:

Table#2

```
| ID  | TRANS. ID | AMOUNT 
| 2   | 30001     |    
| 3   | 30001     | 15
| 4   | 30001     | 
--------------------------   "this line for demonstration only"
| 5   | 30002     |    
| 6   | 30002     | 88
| 7   | 30002     |
```

Comment: I have edited my question with more described problem.

Comment: The desired output isn't a usual SQL design; care to describe what your reasoning is?

Comment: I wanted to to merge similar values under Column (AMOUNT)  into on single values for that particular TRANS. ID, it's something grouping those repeated values for that transaction, so i have just given a sample how the result will be

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't use LAG because that's only in 2012 or newer, you can do similar trick with row_number:

```
select
  ID, TRANSID, case when RN = 1 then AMOUNT else NULL end as AMOUNT
from
(
  select
    row_number() over (partition by TRANSID order by ID) as RN, *
  from 
    YourTable
) X
```

Example in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b10fa/1)

Comment: Is there any other way to cater this?

Comment: Yes there is, several other ways. What's wrong with this one?

Comment: i was getting errors while implementing this with my UNION query, It would be helpful if you can share another method.

Comment: Another method is doing a case with if exists back to the table, but there's no reason why this shouldn't work with any query

Comment: Can you share with me, how to use this logic?